# ELI5: what Microlocal analysis (generalization of Fourier analysis) generalizes? What does it do?

Tags: fourier-analysis, microlocal-analysis

I understand the concept of the Fourier transform or (at least) what it does. You split a complex signal into simple parts.

But what does the microlocal analysis do, a generalisation of Fourier transforms? Does it let you decompose signals in a curved space?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microlocal_analysis

> The term microlocal implies localisation not only with respect to location in the space, but also with respect to cotangent space directions at a given point. This gains in importance on manifolds of dimension greater than one.

Can you provide an example of a "practical" use? At least in some fictional world?

I am little experienced in math, hence "ELI5" (if possible)

Comment: The answers here discuss common ones https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258756/applications-of-microlocal-analysis

Comment: @Ninad Munshi the medical example is super mega unbelievably great, but is not very elaborate for a non-expert

But I am not asking to explain everything in every detail!

Although I see there's a link to an article that looks like it can be grasped by a non-expert... thank you very much!